# Is the new System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache class per session or per application?

Tags: .net, caching, .net-4.0

I know System.Web.Caching.Cache is per application, is the new System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache class in .net 4.0 per session or per application?

Is there any way to do cache per session without using the session variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the new class is designed for .NET apps that not ASP.NET apps, that it would be per application.